# Cannot publish package - I cannot publish 2.0.0 as the initial version

Tags: elm

I have published package using elm-0.18 after elm-0.19 was released.

Now I have upgraded it to elm-0.19 but I cannot publish it:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/elm publish
This package has never been published before. Here's how things work:

  - Versions all have exactly three parts: MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH

  - All packages start with initial version 1.0.0

  - Versions are incremented based on how the API changes:

        PATCH = the API is the same, no risk of breaking code
        MINOR = values have been added, existing values are unchanged
        MAJOR = existing values have been changed or removed

  - I will bump versions for you, automatically enforcing these rules


I will now verify that everything is in order...

  + Found README.md
  + Found LICENSE
  X Version 2.0.0 is not correct!

-- INVALID VERSION -------------------------------------------------------------

I cannot publish 2.0.0 as the initial version.

Change it to 1.0.0 which is the initial version for all Elm packages.
```

Comment: The CLI seems to think that package has never been published. Double check the name in your `elm.json` file, and make sure it exists on package.elm-lang.org

Comment: @Sidney it exists on package.elm-lang.org. I can find it at https://dmy.github.io/elm-0.18-packages/

Comment: What happens if you try to publish it with version `1.0.0`?

Comment: I have published it with version 1.0.0 and elm-0.19

Comment: Weird.  I would post on https://discourse.elm-lang.org/ and see whether this is expected behaviour or not.